# Old Log home leaking

Tags: electrical-panel, roof, waterproofing, leaking

We recently purchased a 1975 log home in Northern British Columbia Canada.  We knew it would require fixing up. We immediately had to get jobs so it has been slow going. When it rain we had a few leaks that we dealt with using caulking. Now it is winter and it is a whole new game. This past few days has been -30 to -40 degrees celcius.  It "warmed" up to -15 today and we have water seepage in logs and by windows.The one area leaking water has got us extremely concerned as it is near our 100 amp panel in our kitchen. Our cabin is just 500 sq feet.  Basiclly one room with small addition and lofts for sleeping. Is there anything we can do right now in the middle of a winter.Can we caulk or seal somehow while cold and wet ?. It is supposed to dramatically warm up this week from 0 to -5 degrees celcius so we know some water will be leaking. We are very worried.

Comment: There are various roofing products for cold/wet conditions (when you find your roof leaks). Exact parameters vary by product, so check the labels at your local supplier (hopefully actually local).

Comment: I forgot to add there is no tar paper under tin. We discovered this in novemeber as the roofing aeason had already passed in our cold climate.

Comment: The short term answer may involve tarps over the whole roof (and weights to keep them there. Not pretty but…

Comment: I agree. Might be necessary

Comment: Do you know the source of the water, since it is not raining there? Melting snow and ice? Condensation where your warm interior air hits cold walls? Cold causing shrinkage of logs/caulking and thus opening up leaks?

Comment: Armand. I think it is condensation when really cold. We had the blaze king wood stove really hot at -4 0 degrees celcius as our pipes froze !! Now it  is melting snow. The temp just went from -40 degrees celcius to 1 degree celcius today. Just wild.